# json using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a json file. Now I want to read it contents using jquery. One way is to use $.getJSON() method and there some other jquery json methods which could be used but these methods will send request to the server and read the contents and send the contents to the client. Is it possible to read .json file contents without sending request to the server?

Here is my menu.json file which is basically taken from json.org example. I need this for simple demo purpose.

```
{
    "menu": {
        "id": "file",
        "value": "File",
        "popup": {
            "menuitem": [
                {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
                {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
                {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

menu.json file is in my file system like this

```
projectfolder/
    index.html
    menu.json
```

Comment: Where is the file stored?  If its stored on your server then you'll need to make a request to the server

Comment: You could assign the above to a variable, and then convert it to objects using jQuery. There is a utility method to do that, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of your files are initially stored on the server.  If you want to access them on the client then you will need to, in some form or fashion, make a request to the server. `$.getJSON()` is an excellent way to do that.

If this is just data that you want to store and doesn't need to be human edited or accessed by other applications, you can just save it as a javascript object in your code

```
var obj = {
    menu: {
        id: "file",
        value: "File",
        popup: {
            menuitem: [
                {value: "New", onclick: CreateNewDoc},
                {value: "Open", onclick: OpenDoc},
                {value: "Close", onclick: CloseDoc}
            ]
        }
    }
};
```

Since you apparently want to store functions in it, this is a better approach.  Eval-ing functions saved as strings on the client is not considered great practice, as you're tightly binding your data to your implementation, and theoretically allowing for arbitrary functions to be bound to the onclick here.